# Confirm mobile number in PayPal

Tags: paypal, verification, phone-number

I've set up a new PayPal account and the Summary page asks me to confirm my mobile number.

[image]

When I click the link, it just takes me to my *Settings* page. There's no option to confirm my mobile number on that page. I can add a new phone number or edit my existing number, but neither gives the option to *confirm* that number.

What do I need to do to confirm the mobile number I've already set?

Comment: There are two places I can think of:
1) Activate your phone number as your security key (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_security-token)
2) Set a mobile PIN (https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_mobile-change-pin)
I have both set and my profile is 100%. I can’t find any other place that is related to your mobile phone number.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the Setting gear button from the top right
2. Click on the *Update* link besides your mobile number
   [image]

And now you will be able to edit your mobile number and confirm it.

Comment: I guess it used to work this way (Google cache: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:I1LwHaVtRiEJ:https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-confirm-my-mobile-number-faq3044+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=fi&client=opera) but there's no longer such action available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing all numbers than adding the primary as your cell? You must pick the "mobile" option on the "type of phone" menu. Choosing a home line doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: There's no option for mobile vs landline (maybe differs per country).